# Python egg not accessible after installation

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am attempting to build an egg and install it using easy_install from within a virtualenv.

Setup.py lives in a directory above the 'autodeploy directory and 'looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='autodeploy',
    version='0.1',
    description='autodeployment tool',
    author='abc',
    author_email='a@bc.com',
    url='http://localhost',
    packages=['autodeploy'])
```

I build an egg:

```
(venv) deploy $python setup.py bdist_egg
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing autodeploy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to autodeploy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to autodeploy.egg-info/top_level.txt
package init file 'autodeploy/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'autodeploy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'autodeploy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying autodeploy.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying autodeploy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying autodeploy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying autodeploy.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.13-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
(venv) deploy $
```

No I install:

```
(venv) deploy $easy_install dist/autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg
Processing autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg
Removing /Users/joe/Desktop/deploy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg
Copying autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg to /Users/joe/Desktop/deploy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
autodeploy 0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Users/joe/Desktop/deploy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for autodeploy==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for autodeploy==0.1
(venv) deploy $
```

However, the utility is not accessible for me - both inside or outside the venv. If I use pip to list the utility, I see it:

```
(venv) deploy $pip show autodeploy
Name: autodeploy
Version: 0.1
Summary: autodeployment tool
Home-page: http://localhost
Author: abc
Author-email: a@bc.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/joe/Desktop/deploy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autodeploy-0.1-py3.6.egg
Requires:
Required-by:
(venv) deploy $
```

Comment: *the utility is not accessible for me* — what does it mean? What have you tried and what's the error?